# Is it possible to undo kubernetes cluster delete command?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, devops

Is it possible to undo "gcloud container clusters delete" command?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not: [Deleting a Cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/deleting-a-cluster#before_you_begin)

All the source volumes and data (that are not persistent) are removed, and unless you made a conscious choice to take a backup of the cluster, it would be a permanent operation.

If a backup does exist, it would be a restore from backup rather than a revert on the delete command.

I suggest reading a bit more into the Administration of a cluster on Gcloud for more info: [Administration of Clusters Overview](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-admin-overview)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if you will delete cluster it is impossible to undo this.

In the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/delete) you can check what will be deleted after `gcloud container clusters delete` and what will remain after this command.
One of the things which will remain is `Persistent disk volumes`. It means that if your `ClaimPolicy` was set to `Retain` and your PV status is `Released` you will be able to get data from `PersistentVolume`. To do that you will have to create `PersistentVolumeClain`. More info about `ReclaimPolicy`[here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-pv-reclaim-policy/#why-change-reclaim-policy-of-a-persistentvolume).

Run `$ kubectl get pv` to check if it is still bound and check `ReclaimPolicy`. Similar case can be found in [this github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/48609) thread.

In [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/) you can find step by stop how to connect pod to specific PV.

In addition, please note that you can backup your cluster. To do this you can use for example [Ark](https://itsmetommy.com/2018/10/28/kubernetes-cluster-backup-with-heptio-ark-on-gcp/).